# iOS don't killing correctly app - Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

When you leave the application approximately 3 or more hours in iOS in the background, it does not kill the application correctly, this causes index.html to be blank in the safari development console.

> engine name="ios" spec="4.4.0"

Ionic info

```
ionic -version 3.20.0
ionic info
cli packages: (C:\Users\Usuario Interax\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
Node : v6.11.5
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 10
Misc:
backend : pro
```

I found this print in console:

> exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova
>   global code about:blank 1:127
>   global code script element 1:1:127

The application stop in splashscreen and don't go to principal screen.

Searching more thoroughly found this:

```
exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova
try {
cordova.require('cordova/exec').nativeEvalAndFetch(function() {
    cordova.fireDocumentEvent('active');
})
} catch (e) {
console.log('exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ' + e);
};
```

The bug only happens in iOS, Android works good.

Comment: can you specify your question? are you reporting a bug? or seeking for a solution?

Comment: i will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Cheking this post: https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/35329/post-ios-11-3-mobile-app-freeze-crash-on-resume-after-sleep-silk-ui/

I tested it in iOS version 10.3.3 and the function of the application is correct, so there is an error in the new version 11.3 and also in the 11.4.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in a pullrequest in the cordova-ios repository (see https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/363/files 38). Nevertheless, there does not exist an update with this PR yet. Therefore, I decided to download the fixed file and after adding the ios platform, I replace the old CDVViewController.m on my own. For me this worked and my > 2000 user do not experience this issue anymore.

The path to the old file is platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVViewController.m.

Remember to replace this file everytime after removing/adding the platform. I use for this (and other things) a shellscript to prepare my working directory before building.

I hope this will help you.

Gratitude Mike1707 to provide a workaround Forum response https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-with-ios-in-the-background-after-time/131592/6